# How to make pymongo aggregation with count all elements and grouping by one request

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with fields like this:

```py
{
    "_id":"5cf54857bbc85fd0ff5640ba",
    "book_id":"5cf172220fb516f706d00591",
    "tags":{
        "person":[
            {"start_match":209, "length_match":6, "word":"kimmel"}
        ],
        "organization":[
            {"start_match":107, "length_match":12, "word":"philadelphia"},
            {"start_match":209, "length_match":13, "word":"kimmel center"}
        ],
        "location":[
            {"start_match":107, "length_match":12, "word":"philadelphia"}
        ]
    },
    "deleted":false
}
```

I want to collect the different words in the categories and count it.
So, the output should be like this:

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "tag": "location",
            "tag_list": [
                {
                    "count": 31,
                    "phrase": "philadelphia"
                },
                {
                    "count": 15,
                    "phrase": "usa"
                }
             ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "organization",
            "tag_list": [ ... ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "person",
            "tag_list": [ ... ]
        },
    ]
}
```

The pipeline like this works:

```py
def pipeline_func(tag):
    return [
        {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': '$tags'}},
        {'$unwind': '${}'.format(tag)},
        {'$group': {'_id': '${}.word'.format(tag), 'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
        {'$project': {'phrase': '$_id', 'count': 1, '_id': 0}},
        {'$sort': {'count': -1}}
    ]
```

But it make a request for each tag. I want to know how to make it in one request.
Thank you for attention.

Comment: *"The pipeline like this works..."* - Actually it **cannot** as presented since `tags` is shown as an **object** `{}` and not an **array** `[]` in the question. So `{ $unwind: "$tags" }` would **throw an error** ( `$unwind` **only** works on actual **arrays** ). I suggest that either your actual data has a *slightly* different structure, OR your claimed pipeline attempt does not actually work . You need to **clearly** specify which of those two options are actually true. An edit to your question would be appropriate here.

Comment: It's strange, but when I remove the  `{ $unwind: "$tags" }` the output doesn't change. Maybe It happens because of lists are inside. But you are right. `{ $unwind: "$tags" }` is unnecessary. I remove it from my request, but my answer it still actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, there is a *slight* mismatch in the question data to the current claimed pipeline process since [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) can **only** be used on *arrays* and the `tags` as presented in the question is *not an array*.

For the data presented in the question you basically want a pipeline like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "tags": { "$objectToArray": "$tags" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  { "$unwind": "$tags.v" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "tag": "$tags.k",
      "phrase": "$tags.v.word"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.tag",
    "tag_list": {
      "$push": {
        "count": "$count",
        "phrase": "$_id.phrase"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Again as per the note, since `tags` is in fact an **object** then what you actually need in order to collect data based on it's *sub-keys* as the question is asking, is to turn that essentially into an *array* of items.

The usage of [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) in your current pipeline would seem to indicate that [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) is of *fair use* here, as it is available from later patch releases of MongoDB 3.4, being the bare minimal version you *should* be using in production right now.

That [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) actually does pretty much what the name says and produces an array ( or "list" to be more *pythonic* ) of entries broken into *key* and *value* pairs. These are essentially a "list" of *objects* ( or "dict" entries ) which have the keys `k` and `v` respectively. The output of the first pipeline stage would look like this on the supplied document:

```
{
  "book_id": "5cf172220fb516f706d00591",
  "tags": [
    {
      "k": "person",
      "v": [
        {
          "start_match": 209,
          "length_match": 6,
          "word": "kimmel"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "k": "organization",
      "v": [
        {
          "start_match": 107,
          "length_match": 12,
          "word": "philadelphia"
        }, {
          "start_match": 209,
          "length_match": 13,
          "word": "kimmel center"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "k": "location",
      "v": [
        {
          "start_match": 107,
          "length_match": 12,
          "word": "philadelphia"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "deleted" : false
}
```

So you should be able to see how you can now easily access those `k` values and use them in *grouping*, and of course the `v` is the standard array as well. So it's just the **two** [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stages as shown and then **two** [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages. Being the first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in order to collection over the combination of keys, and the second to *collect* as per the main grouping key whilst adding the other accumulations to a *"list"* within that entry.

Of course the output by the above listing is not *exactly* how you asked for in the question, but the data is basically there. You can optionally add an [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to essentially rename the `_id` key as the final aggregation stage:

```
  { "$addFields": {
    "_id": "$$REMOVE",
    "tag": "$_id"
  }}
```

Or simply do something *pythonic* with a little list comprehension on the cursor output:

```
cursor = db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "tags": { "$objectToArray": "$tags" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  { "$unwind": "$tags.v" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "tag": "$tags.k",
      "phrase": "$tags.v.word"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.tag",
    "tag_list": {
      "$push": {
        "count": "$count",
        "phrase": "$_id.phrase"
      }
    }
  }}
])

output = [{ 'tag': doc['_id'], 'tag_list': doc['tag_list'] } for doc in cursor]

print({ 'response': output });
```

And final output as a *"list"* you can use for `response`:

```
{
  "tag_list": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "phrase": "philadelphia"
    }
  ],
  "tag": "location"
},
{
  "tag_list": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "phrase": "kimmel"
    }
  ],
  "tag": "person"
},
{
  "tag_list": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "phrase": "kimmel center"
    }, {
      "count": 1,
      "phrase": "philadelphia"
    }
  ],
  "tag": "organization"
}
```

Noting that using a *list comprehension* approach you have a bit more control over the order of "keys" as output, as MongoDB itself would simply *append NEW* key names in a projection keeping existing keys ordered first. If that sort of thing is important to you that is. Though it really should not be since all Object/Dict like structures should not be considered to have any set order of keys. That's what arrays ( or lists ) are for.

Comment: All work. It's a brilliant answer. Nothing to add. Thank you for quick response. +1.